# PHP loop for TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

please help this idiot. I know there are a lot of examples but none makes sense to me and cant get it to work. I need to create a loop (i think) to display all the records in the db. Currently only one record is displayed

Existing code

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    //ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('connection.php');    



    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblbtcmembers order by mname");


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
       $pid = $row['pid'];  
       $mname = $row['mname'];
       $msurname = $row['msurname'];
       $mcontactno = $row['mcontactno'];
       $memail = $row['memail'];
       $mkennelname = $row['mkennelname'];

      }

      // Get UserID   
    $userid=$_SESSION['account_id'];
    $username=$_SESSION['login_id'];                     





    //============================================================+
    // File name   : example_048.php
    // Begin       : 2009-03-20
    // Last Update : 2013-05-14
    //
    // Description : Example 048 for TCPDF class
    //               HTML tables and table headers
    //
    // Author: Nicola Asuni
    //
    // (c) Copyright:
    //               Nicola Asuni
    //               Tecnick.com LTD
    //               www.tecnick.com
    //               info@tecnick.com
    //============================================================+

    /**
     * Creates an example PDF TEST document using TCPDF
     * @package com.tecnick.tcpdf
     * @abstract TCPDF - Example: HTML tables and table headers
     * @author Nicola Asuni
     * @since 2009-03-20
     */

    // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
    require_once('tcpdf_include_litter_reg.php');

    // Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
    class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

        //Page header
        public function Header() {
            // Logo
            $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'tcpdf_logo-bak-20aug-15.jpg';
            $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, '', '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
             // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
             // Position at 273 mm from bottom
            $this->SetY(-273);
            // Position at 40 mm from left
            $this->SetX(40);
            // Title
           $this->Cell(120, 15, 'Biewer Terrier Club Member List', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');

        }  

        // Page footer
        public function Footer() {
            // Position at 15 mm from bottom
            $this->SetY(-15);
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
            // Page number
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');


        }
    }

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('BTCSA');
    $pdf->SetTitle('MemberList');
    $pdf->SetSubject('MemberList');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('MemberList');

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);



    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);


    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Table with rowspans and THEAD
    $tbl = <<<EOD



    $html <br>
    $html <br>
    $html <hr> 
    $html <p> </p>


    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">


      <tr>
        <th style="background-color:#ddd;" align="center" width="30"><b>SN</b></th>
        <th style="background-color:#ddd;" align="left"><b>Name</b></th>
        <th style="background-color:#ddd;" align="left"><b>Surname</b></th>
        <th style="background-color:#ddd;" align="left"><b>Contact No</b></th>
        <th style="background-color:#ddd;" align="left" width="170"><b>E-MAIL</b></th>
        <th style="background-color:#ddd;" align="left"><b>Kennel</b></th>
       </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>$pid</td>
       <td>$mname</td>
      <td>$msurname</td>
       <td>$mcontactno</td>
        <td>$memail</td>
        <td>$mkennelname</td>
      </tr>



     </table> 
    $html <br>
    $html <hr> 


    $html <li style="font-size:6px;">Requested By: $username</li> 

    EOD;

    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output('printmember.pdf', 'I');

    //============================================================+
    // END OF FILE
    //============================================================+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting one row. Aren't you? Variables inside the loop are only valid inside the scope of the loop. What you should do is loop over the table rows whilst concatenating  the string to pass to the pdf

Comment: Jip, exactly as you say - only getting one row. My issue is I have no clue how to create the loop or really understand it - this is all totally new to me, try to learn something new as a hobby - can you perhaps refer me to a link which can guide me

Comment: Little example:
$tablebody = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch.......){
        $tablerow = "<tr><td>Contact</td><td>$row['contact']</td>";
$tablebody += $tablerow;
}

go on and add the other columns and you ll get all the rows you need.